# Sending a CoreData NSManagedObject to Another Player in Game Center

Tags: ios, core-data, game-center

How do I send a core data object called Deck *deck, which contains an NSString, an NSData photograph object, and an NSSet (a one-many relationship to other entities).

When I tried to send the Deck *deck using the [GKMatch sendData:toPlayers:] method, the NSData *outgoingPacket remained nil, but *deck had an address, according to the debug console.

```
- (void) sendDeck {

    NSError *error;
    NSData *outgoingPacket = [NSData dataWithBytes:&_deck length:sizeof(_deck)];
    [self.myMatch sendData:outgoingPacket toPlayers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.pickerViewFriend] withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable error:&error];

//myMatch is an instance of GKMatch.
//_deck is an instance variable set by @property Deck *deck, which is assigned by a UIPickerView, which works perfectly

}
```

(I realize this doesn't even address sending the cards associated with the deck, but I'm stuck at this point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this line:

```
NSData *outgoingPacket = [NSData dataWithBytes:&_deck length:sizeof(_deck)];
```

1. Since `_deck` is a pointer to an object (an instance of `Deck`), `sizeof(_deck)` just gives you the size of the pointer. That's just big enough for a single memory address.
2. You can't really fix the call because `dataWithBytes:length:` works with a contiguous block of memory. Your managed object is extremely unlikely to pass that test.

You could send each field independently, but that's kind of messy. An easier alternative would be to use `NSDictionary` as your transfer object. Convert between `NSDictionary` and `Deck` as needed, and encode `NSDictionary` as an `NSData` for transfer. Something like:

```
NSDictionary *dict = // Fill this with the values you want to send
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict];
```

Then at the other end,

```
NSData *data = // data received from other device
NSDictionary *dict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Your solution worked! Thank you very much! The only problem I have is with "unpacking" my NSManagedObject into an NSMutableDictionary. I had to manually enter the CoreData Entity's attributes as @{key:object}; then I had to do the same thing for each entity that had a relationship to the previous entity. My data model is pretty simple for now, and it still took a long time. What would I do if I had a huge data model with numerous entities and relationships?

Comment: You could implement `NSCoding` methods for `NSManagedObject` using introspection of Core Data properties. Core Data supports only few data types, so that should really be no problem to do.